# Need help creating a program to read in entries and replace existing entry if there is one for that date

Tags: java, arrays, search, replace

I am very new to coding and learning java, I can picture what the program needs to do however implementing to code has proven tough for me. I am trying to create a constructor. The constructor needs to do the following-
Constructor: When reading in and storing the individual quiz data, you will need to watch out for repeated quizzes. If a quiz is read in with a date that already has an entry stored, you will need to replace the earlier entry with the new one. I have been provided a java doc for this, however I will need to create the code. I have attached an image of the javadoc as well as the code that I currently have.

[Javadoc for Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjXk5.png)

```
public QuizList(String filename)
{
    this.quizzesList = 0;
    this.quizList = new ArrayList<Quiz>();

    try {
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (infile.hasNextLine()){
            String quizDate = infile.next();
            String pointsEarned = infile.next();
            String possiblePoints = infile.nextLine().trim();
            Quiz quiz = new Quiz(quizDate, points, possible);
            this.quizzes.add(quiz);
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No such file: " + filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

File has lastModified method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html.
I recommend you to iterate the files on the directory and check their last modified date.